# Windows 10 having trouble with battery status

Tags: battery, windows-10-preview, windows-insider

Windows 10 not updating battery status

[image]

This happens after windows update

Comment: "his happens after windows update" which one? What is your hardware?

Comment: @MátéJuhász 16226 build, i have dell inspiron 3558

Comment: is the question answered?

Comment: @magicandre1981 unfortunately no , but I read some blogs and they say uninstall battery driver then shut down remove batter then press and hold power button for 10 min then start , not worked for me , I still have to disable and renable  the battery driver for update battery %

Comment: as I said this is a known issue with last insider builds. We can't answer anything else. I posted the **correct answer**, [so accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  I'm out of the topic now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in the latest Insider build that we can't fix. [Microsoft asks for feedback](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16226-pc/) about it and the user can only send Feedback via the feedback hub app so that Microsoft can fix it in the final of the Fall Creators Update.

Comment: MS fixed it in Build 16241

Comment: In the future, please Edit your question with answers to comments so it's easier for future users to read.

Comment: have you updated your Insider Build to 16241? Does it update again?

Comment: @magicandre yes and everything is OK

Comment: ok, in this case accept my reply as answer, I've answered it correctly twice now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known issue with the [Insider versions between Build 16226](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16226-pc/) and 16237

> We’re investigating your reports that the battery status on certain
>   laptops isn’t updating while the device is unplugged.

that Microsoft fixed it in [Build 16241](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/07/13/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16241-pc-build-15230-mobile/):

> We fixed an issue where the battery status on certain laptops wasn’t
>   updating while the device is unplugged. Thanks everyone who shared
>   logs to help narrow this down.

So run Windows Update to get the lastest Build and look if the issue is fixed,